# How can I tell if an SWT Shell was closed programmatically or by the user?

Tags: java, event-handling, swt

I know I can use this code to tell when the shell is closed,

```
shell.addShellListener(new ShellAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void shellClosed(ShellEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("closed");
    }
}
```

But the `ShellEvent` object doesn't tell me whether the Shell was closed programmatically or when the user clicked on the X button.

Is there a way to tell?

Comment: Can you explain your use-case to us? I don't see why you would have to know that. Can't you just do what you want to do wherever you call `shell.close()`?

Comment: I tried couple of ways to figure out how can this be done. The problem is in any way you close Shell, it is invoking org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.closeWidget(). I am afraid there is not other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent some time to distinguish if the Close `ShellEvent` is generated by **User** or **System**.

After inspecting the `ShelEvent` on both the cases the only variable with a different value through out the ObjectGraph of `ShellEvent` is `captureChanged` in the `Display` class whose scope is `default`

The below code should help you find the source of the `ShellEvent`

```
shell.addShellListener(new ShellAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void shellClosed(ShellEvent e) {

                Field f = Display.class.getDeclaredField("captureChanged");
                f.setAccessible(true);
                System.out.println("captureChanged = " + f.get(e.display)); //true = If User triggered the Event
                System.out.println("closed");
        }
    });
```

Comment: I get the following exception: `java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: captureChanged`.

Comment: @Baz I could find it in `org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_3.7.0.v3735b.jar`. It might be missing in `swt.jar` of other platforms. Hmm!!

Comment: Yeah, I can verify, that it's part of the windows library, but not part of the linux nor the osx library.

Comment: @marcolopes If you could debug and inspect the ShellEvent in both the cases on your environment you may find any difference. Not sure if there can be any workaround if you could not find any differences.